# Boltzmann Equation - reference request

Tags: reference-request, partial-differential-equations, mathematical-physics

I'm looking for an **introductory** text on the theory of the Boltzmann equation. I'd be particularly happy with a short, self-contained text, e.g. a tutorial / set of lecture notes, but longer references would also be welcome. I also suspect there may be more general textbooks on PDE which include a section about the Boltzmann equation - this would also be suitable for my purposes.

Thus far, I've been working from Villani's "A review of mathematical topics in collisional kinetic theory". Whilst thorough and well-written, it is quite densely filled with references to other works. In line with this, I'm seeking a more elementary, restricted reference to complement Villani's review.

If relevant, my ultimate plan is to work towards understanding the theorems of Ukai (short-range interactions) and Gressman-Strain (long-range interactions). I should emphasise, however, that my reason for seeking a reference is to build my introductory knowledge of the Boltzmann equation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like very much [Mathematical Statistical Mechanics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0024206709), which can be used for "introductory knowledge".

Comment: Thank you - I will check out the chapter on kinetic theory and see how suitable it is. Appreciate the suggestion.

Comment: Having read through the chapter, I'm very happy with this - it develops the equation nicely in stages, starting with the simple Kroenig-Clausius model, building up to the Maxwell distribution, and then the Boltzmann equation, first in a spatially homogeneous gas and then in the more general case. A really nice, graded development of the ideas around the Boltzmann equation in quite simple terms. Many thanks.

Comment: Glad you found it useful.

Answer (score 1):

The classic lecture "Lectures on Gas Theory":

- [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00A73IPJ8](http://ttps://www.amazon.com/dp/B00A73IPJ8)

Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy:

- [Boltzmann’s Work in Statistical Physics](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/statphys-Boltzmann/)

and this seems worth a read...

- [Numerical Solution of Boltzmann's Equation](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/B9780121740702500071)